# Fade Video-Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

I am using below command to add Fade In Fade Out effect to my video

```
{"-y", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-i", inputPath, "-acodec", "copy", "-vf", "fade=t=in:st=0:d=5,fade=t=out:st=" + String.valueOf((endMs - startMs) / 1000 - 5) + ":d=5", outputPath};
```

I received below error-

> "Failure3.3 5 .3gpffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the
>   FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)\n  configuration:
>   --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=\n  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103\n  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102\n  libavformat    57. 25.100 /
>   57. 25.100\n  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101\n  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100\n  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100\n  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101\n  libpostproc    54.  0.100 /
>   54.  0.100\nInput #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20180825_071734915.3gp':\n 
>   Metadata:\n    major_brand     : 3gp4\n    minor_version   : 0\n
>   compatible_brands: isom3gp4\n    creation_time   : 2018-08-25
>   01:47:47\n    com.android.version: 8.0.0\n  Duration: 00:00:10.83,
>   start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17217 kb/s\n    Stream #0:0(eng): Video:
>   h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt470bg/unknown),
>   1920x1080, 16756 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.49 fps, 29.58 tbr, 90k
>   tbn, 180k tbc (default)\n    Metadata:\n      rotate          : 90\n
>   creation_time   : 2018-08-25 01:47:47\n      handler_name    :
>   VideoHandle\n    Side data:\n      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00
>   degrees\n    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D),
>   48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)\n    Metadata:\n
>   creation_time   : 2018-08-25 01:47:47\n      handler_name    :
>   SoundHandle\n[h263 @ 0xf49ff400] H.263 does not support resolutions
>   above 2048x1152\nOutput #0, 3gp, to
>   '/storage/emulated/0/Movies/fade_video.3gp':\n  Metadata:\n
>   major_brand     : 3gp4\n    minor_version   : 0\n
>   compatible_brands: isom3gp4\n    com.android.version: 8.0.0\n
>   Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h263, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR
>   0:0, 29.58 fps (default)\n    Metadata:\n      handler_name    :
>   VideoHandle\n      creation_time   : 2018-08-25 01:47:47\n
>   encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 h263\n    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac
>   (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, 128 kb/s (default)\n
>   Metadata:\n      creation_time   : 2018-08-25 01:47:47\n
>   handler_name    : SoundHandle\nStream mapping:\n  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0
>   (h264 (native) -> h263 (native))\n  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)\nError
>   while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect
>   parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height\n"

Why is causing this error in above command?Any help will be welcome.

Comment: As the log says, *H.263 does not support resolutions above 2048x1152*. Your source stream is 1920x1080 but it's 90 deg rotated so ffmpeg is auto-rotating it to 1080x1920 which does not meet the limits. You can add a scale filter after the fade to downsize.

Comment: @Gyan Okay..so i want that if resolution is 2048x1152 or below it should not scale my video..but if its above than it should scale down my video..will adding `scale='min(2048,iw)':'min(1152,ih)'` meets my requirement and resolve my issue?Like-`{"-y", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-i", inputPath, "-acodec", "copy", "-vf", "fade=t=in:st=0:d=5,fade=t=out:st=" + String.valueOf((endMs - startMs) / 1000 - 5) + ":d=5,scale='min(2048,iw)':'min(1152,ih)'", outputPath}`;

Comment: `scale='if(lte(iw,2048)*lte(ih,1152),iw,if(gt(dar,2048/1152),2048,oh*dar))':'if(lte(iw,2048)*lte(ih,1152),ih,if(gt(dar,2048/1152),ow/dar,1152))'`

Comment: @Gyan Glad if you can post it as an answer with explanation so that i can understand properly and accept it as correct answer.What is "dar" in parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the log says, H.263 does not support resolutions above 2048x1152. Your source stream is 1920x1080 but it's 90 deg rotated so ffmpeg is auto-rotating it to 1080x1920 which does not meet the limits. You can add a scale filter after the fade to conditionally downsize.

`scale='if(lte(iw,2048)*lte(ih,1152),iw,if(gt(dar,2048/1152),2048,2*trunc(oh*dar/2)))':'if(lte(iw,2048)*lte(ih,1152),ih,if(gt(dar,2048/1152),2*trunc(ow/dar/2),1152))'`

What the x and y exprs do is first check if the input is greater than 2048x1152. If no, keep original resolution. If yes, check display ratio of input. If greater than 2048:1152, downsize width to 2048 and proportionally resize height, else downsize height to 1152 and proportionally resize width. `dar` stands for display aspect ratio.

Comment: So my command should look like- `{"-y", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, "-i", inputFilePath, "-acodec", "copy", "-vf", "fade=t=in:st=0:d=5,fade=t=out:st=" + String.valueOf((endMs - startMs) / 1000 - 5) + ":d=5,scale='if(lte(iw,2048)*lte(ih,1152),iw,if(gt(dar,2048/1152),2048,oh*dar))':'if(lte(iw,2048)*lte(ih,1152),ih,if(gt(dar,2048/1152),ow/dar,1152))", outputFilePath};`?

Comment: I also sometimes get "height not divisible by 2 " error?What change should i make in above scale parameter to make sure that error doesn't occur?

Comment: while resizing height you are using-`2*trunc(oh*dar/2)` but while resizing width you are using-`2*trunc(ow/dar/2)`?Shouldn't it be -`2*trunc(ow*dar/2)`?Why dividing original width by dar?

Comment: The first expr is for width, not height. `dar = display width / height`.